# Redirect user to logout from previous system while not allowing login from multiple system

Tags: php, session

I am building a system in PHP where we do not want to allow user to be loggedin from 2 diff systems.

1. So a user tries to log in on system1.
2. On successful authorization and authentication, I am storing his session id in DB.
3. User is still logged in on system1, and he tries to login on system2.
4. On successful authorization and authentication on system2, I am fetching his stored session id.
5. I impersonate the session with existing session id, and destroys the session.
6. I store new session id created in step 4, and log user in.

Now, after step 5 I want the client on system1 to redirect the user to login/logout page automatically. How can I do that?

I am thinking of using SSE, but it is not supported in all browsers.

This is the code for step 5 -

```
public static function destroyExistingSession($existingSessId){
    if (session_id()) {
        session_commit();
    }
    //commit current
    session_start();
    $currentSessId = SessionManagement::getCurrentSessionId();
    session_commit();

    //remove existing
    session_id($existingSessId);
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    session_commit();

    //restore to current
    session_id($currentSessId);
    session_start();
    session_commit();
}
```

Comment: Traditional approach is to handle on next request... then with no session redirect to logn/signed off page.  Sounds like you want something more event driven... Maybe add the [`sse`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sse) tag if you want that answer.

Comment: You could store sessions in a separate table, then check if there is more than one session for a specific user, and check if the session on that system equals the last session stored on the database, if it equals an old session, kick him out.

Comment: @ficuscr : SSE is not supported in IE. So that cannot be a solution for me.

Comment: @Condorcho - That part is already handled. The problem is how to redirect the client when session is kicked out.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal what happens if someone reaches one of these pages, using a bookmark for example, when not logged in?  What I'm saying is that same scenario would cover what you are asking.

Comment: That part is already handled. The problem is to send info from server to client on an event / function call / flow (probably without sse if possible)